# Rule Rewrite Alterando diretórios dos scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-amigável

Estou com o seguinte problema, ao utilizar o rule abaixo meu diretório padrão é alterado e meus *scripts js* e arquivos *css* param de funcionar.

```
<rule name="Produtos Detalhe">
   <match url="^(produto)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/?$"  />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/Produto/Detalhe?id={R:3}"  />
</rule>
```

Exemplo, este código:

```
<link href="@Href("~/Content/Site/css/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet">
```

Está ficando assim depois de renderizado:

```
<link href="/produto/Content/Site/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Gostaria que ficasse:

```
<link href="/Content/Site/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Já tentou tirar o til dessa instrução? `@Href("~/Content/Site/css/bootstrap.min.css")`

Answer (score 0):

É simples.
Seu rule está como regra geral, na base, o diretório produto.
como você mesmo pode ver, tudo e qualquer url que você usar terá automaticamente sempre isso.
Tenta criar uma regra universal.
E com os dados coletados você tenta saber onde está indo no sistema, se for para produtos você ai sim, usa o dir /produtos e caso contrário /.
Fiz isso no apache mas em asp não sei.
Estou tentado só te dar uma luz.

Tenta de deixar assim: `^(.*)\/(.*)\/?$` e depois você cria regras de código a parte para saber se você está no dir produtos.